# Prevent ArgoCD from syncing a single ressource

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, argocd

I have an ArgoCD App which is generating symbols

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  labels:
    {{- include "myapp.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: pre-install,post-delete
  name: {{ include "myapp.fullname" . }}
type: Opaque
data:
  {{- if .Values.password }}
  password: {{ .Values.password | b64enc | quote }}
  {{- else }}
  password: {{ randAlphaNum 10 | b64enc | quote }}
  {{- end }}
```

A second service is adding additional values to the secrets later. I don't want this secrets in my chart

Now when something is changed on the app, the secrets are recreated.

How can i change this behaviour in ArgoCD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add annotation to that particular object and it should work

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  labels:
    {{- include "myapp.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: pre-install,post-delete
    argocd.argoproj.io/sync-options: Prune=false
```

> Some Sync Options can defined as annotations in a specific resource. Most of the Sync Options are configured in the Application resource `spec.syncPolicy.syncOptions` attribute. Multiple Sync Options which are configured with the `argocd.argoproj.io/sync-options` annotation can be concatenated with a , in the annotation value; white spaces will be trimmed.

[no-prune-resources](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/sync-options/#no-prune-resources)

Or if you don’t want to apply auto sync on this object then you can try `ApplyOutOfSyncOnly=false`

[selective-sync](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/user-guide/sync-options/#selective-sync)